# Kubernetes equivalent of Terraform modules and variables

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, containers, terraform

Does Kubernetes have a way of reusing manifests without copying and paste them? Something akin to Terraform templates.

Is there a way of passing values between manifests?

I am looking to deploy the same service to multiple environments and wanted a way to call the necessary manifest and pass in the environment specific values.

I'd also like to do something like:

**Generic-service.yaml**

```
Name={variablename}
```

**Foo-service.yaml**

```
Use=General-service.yaml
variablename=foo-service-api
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/), now part of `kubectl apply -k` is a way to *parameterize* your Kubernetes manifests files.

With Kustomize, you have a *base manifest* file (e.g. of `Deployment`) and then multiple *overlay* directories for parameters e.g. for *test*, *qa* and *prod* environment.

I would recommend to have a look at [Introduction to kustomize](https://speakerdeck.com/spesnova/introduction-to-kustomize).

Before Kustomize it was common to use Helm for this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards Kustomize. It sounds like what I need. Do I need to install Kustomize or is it packaged with Kubectl version 1.14?

Comment: @Confounder it should be included in kubectl 1.14 https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/25/kubernetes-1-14-release-announcement/